# When doing an if in ionic 3 it is taking incorrect values ​as correct

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

**I do an if, it works correctly, but when I enter a value that has the first digit "1", it takes it as a correct data. For example, if I compare 1 <= 2, it is understood that I must give a correct answer and that is the case, but I do 11 <= 2 and in the same way it is a correct data and in this way it behaves with each value that has first "1", help**

codigo ts

```
Pagina: any;
numeros: any;
if (this.Pagina >= this.numeros)
```

Answer (score 0):

Expressions - Comparison operators [Read description Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

```
console.log(1 == 1);
// expected output: true

console.log("1" == 1);
// expected output: true

console.log(1 === 1);
// expected output: true
console.log("1" === 1);
// expected output: false
```

Also Read [converting-strings-to-numbers](https://gomakethings.com/converting-strings-to-numbers-with-vanilla-javascript/)
​

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that only numbers get to the `if` statement (Whether stringified or not), then you can do your comparison like so: `if (Number(this.Pagina) >= (Number(this.numeros))`. It will convert the stringified number to an actual number type.